# TFS 2013 Selenium Test Execution Multiple Issue

Tags: visual-studio, selenium, tfs, continuous-integration

I am working on a CI integration with TFS, been facing multiple issues since weeks and have no clue what is that I am missing here. Ensured all the checklist from MSDN and other information that were available here.

1. I want to build and deploy my selenium test framework in remote build server ( 2008) .
2. Was able to build and drop the files in the shared network path of the build server. Earlier there were multiple issue with unit test dll's and but then with external references I was successful in solving this and able to get the the build without any error.
   3.Was able to check the deployed code in the build machine and the drop folder(Debug files)
   4.This solution runs locally without any issue.
3. The problem is when the test execution starts, we don't see the browser launch when we logon to the build system, however my scripts are able to perform non interactive actions, like opening excel, killing browser, launching webdriver.
4. Its failing because of unavailability of the UI elements to perform click.

Ensured:

**Build is interactive enabled.**
Test agent is interactive enabled.
Test Agent is up and running.
Debug logs shows actual code initiation.
Ensured addition of IDE and reference dlls as copy always and is available in debug folder
Build definition are entered with default template, with all details as mentioned in MSDN 
On Fail Screenshot gives bank screen ( Black) though I have keep open the build system

**Done So far:**
- Referenced all MSDN website for Agent, controller setting and troubleshoot

**Question here is**:
The test server for CI execution is using VS 2010/2012 shell installation. So is there anything I need to worry about.
I don't have option to see VS Developer console to execute script in command line.
When I execute the build from the default template,test agent doesn't even respond in the remote machine  - Checked it keeping the screen open in build machine. So how does I get to see the webdriver initiation from my log file.

Comment: Can the test been finished successfully on local machine? And which browser are you using?